# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Owin.Security

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, .net-assembly

First of all I'm beginner in Asp.Net developer.

I try to develop N-Tier Architecture project which include MVC 5 project, Web Api project with Individual User Accounts(Asp.Net Identity). Also It has class libraries which are Data Access layer and Data layer.

Both of MVC and Web api , I combine Both of two project's Identity models in one class.

On Localhost , They works fine. But I host to local IIS on my computer. I have the issue about Microsoft.Owin.Security

```
Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Owin.Security

(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)



[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +234
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +108
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +25
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +49

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +772
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +259
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +163
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +230
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +76
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +139
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +176
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +882

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +712
```

How could I solve that issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425549/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060716/signalr-2-0-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-owin-security

Comment: I'm sorry , I have noticed that The projects does not have the same version of DLL. Now , it works. Thank you for your kind interest