# How to write a managed C# dll that follows cdecl specification

Tags: c#, dll, cdecl

I need to write a DLL, that follows the cdecl specification, so that it can be called from an existing application which allows embedding of dlls.
Can I write a dll using C# and the dotnet Framework, that follows the cdecl specification? How can this be done?

Thanks
Rene

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225277/calling-managed-code-from-unmanaged-code

Comment: it's called "calling convention", e.g. cdecl, stdcall.